# JSONParser missing token

Tags: apex

So I'm receiving a block of JSON from a web service and I need to grab an authentication token from it. The problem I'm having is that the parser is parsing the entire JSON block and missing the auth token.  Here's the JSON I'm receiving:

```
{  
  "authenticationToken":"DACX2YT087NB8PCMKLLYHF9D5HEFJRYS",
  "_links":{  
    "st:node":{  
      "href":"/twig-cstc3/v1/login"
    },
    "curies":[  
      {  
        "name":"st",
        "href":"https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/rels/{rel}",
        "templated":true
      }
    ]
  },
  "_embedded":{  
    "node":{  
      "name":"Steve Placey",
      "description":"Placey, S. (6909)",
      "nodeCode":"6909",
      "_links":{  
        "self":{  
          "href":"/twig-cstc3/v1/login"
        },
        "events":{  
          "href":"https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/node/14604/calendar"
        },
        "st:calendar":{  
          "href":"https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/node/14604/calendar"
        },
        "st:today":{  
          "href":"https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/node/14604/calendar?from=2015-09-01&to=2015-09-01",
          "title":"Today's events"
        },
        "search":{  
          "href":"https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/vault/search",
          "title":"Vault Search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And, here's my parser code:

```
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'authenticationToken')) {
                // Get the value.
                parser.nextToken();
                xAuthToken = parser.getText();
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing all content away until you come to the first array delimiter which is after the `authenticationToken`.

Changing `JSONToken.START_ARRAY` to `JSONToken.START_OBJECT` will probably fix this.